# Verify the success of a database query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-connection, sqlconnection

I've got this test function to insert some example data into a table. What I want is feedback on the success of the operation. Here's the function:

```
Public Function insertTest(ByVal userEmail As String) As Boolean

        Dim result As Boolean = False

        Try

            Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            connection.Open()
            Dim sqlQuery As String = "insert into _TEST_activityLog values (@userEmail, 'delete', 'folder X')"
            Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
            command.Parameters.Add("@userEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userEmail

            Dim rdr = command.ExecuteReader()
            If rdr.HasRows Then

                MsgBox("Record created successfully")
                command.Dispose()

            End If

            rdr.Close()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

        Return result

    End Function
```

I tried with the `reader` part but it always skips it. By the way, the data is being inserted successfully into the database.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for insert operation, not `ExecuteReader`. If there is an error, it will throw exception. And method returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: So, if I remove the `reader` part, including the `If`, and replace it with `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`, that's enough? I can just put a message before the `catch` stating the operation was successful and one inside the `catch` stating it wasn't?

Comment: You can also get inserted row count by return value of ExecuteNonQuery method.